# Training logistic regression using scikit learn for multi-class classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

As per the [scikit multiclass classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)
Logistic regression can be used for multi-class classification by setting
multi_class=multinomial in the the constructor. But doing this gives error:

Code:

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),('clf', LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'multinomial')),])
text_clf = text_clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

**Error:**

ValueError: Solver liblinear does not support a multinomial backend.

**Can you tell me what is wrong here?**

**Note:** Keeping multi_class to blank i.e. "ovr" is working fine but it fits a binary model for each classifier and I want to try mutlinomial feature also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression):

> Currently the ‘multinomial’ option is supported only by the ‘lbfgs’ and ‘newton-cg’ solvers.

So you need to explicitly set `solver` to `'newton-cg`' or `'lbfgs'`, since the default solver is `'liblinear'`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not providing solver & by default solver is set to '**liblinear**' that does not support multi class.
As per sklearn version 0.20.1, multiclass is being supported by ‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ not by ‘liblinear’ so change your instance creation for LogisticRegression as per following code

```
logReg = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg')
```

solver must be anything from ‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ but can not be left

Comment: How how is your answer anything different from whats being already answered above, more than 3 years ago ?

Comment: Added exact code snippet along with enahncement done to support 2 more solver like sag & saga. It may help to improve the performance & accuracy of the model if these 2 solvers brings any improvement for dependent data used in training the model